# how could i make a launcher with an icon to execute an exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, icons, exe

how could I make a launcher with an icon to execute an exe. I have tried lots of things like resource hacker. but this didn't work has any one got any suggestions

I can make a launcher through batch

Comment: you can create a shortcut to the `bat` and set an icon to it.Or you can change the icon of all bat files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.bat files can't get their own icon. you need to use a shortcut or convert it to a .exe file.

you can use this to convert it to .exe:
http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e